# not able to change theme for ng2-admin

Tags: css, sass, ng2-admin, blur-admin

I am using the [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) theme for development. [DEMO](http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/#/pages/dashboard)

I have followed all these steps mentioned in the [doc](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/014-switch-to-blur-theme/) for changing theme to blur-admin from ng2-admin

While changing the theme everything is working fine except the background of the cards.
It is not using `blur-bg-blurred.jpg` as the background for the cards.

I have added

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
```

in the **.card-header** 
and

```
background: url(../assets/img/blur-bg-blurred.jpg) fixed;
```

in **.card**

from the DevTools of chrome and I got what I need.

I have tried adding the same css from code but nothing worked for me.

Please help me if there is some thing else I need to do, to change the theme from ng2 to blur.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solutions, we can add global styles in the styles.css file under the src folder.